# libcurl replacing carriage return + line feed with only line feed

Tags: c++, ftp, libcurl

I'm writing a FTP client with C++ and libcurl, and I'm having trouble downloading files with the combination CRLF (for context, it's a Windows FileZilla Server and I'm running the client on a Debian WSL).

My problem is that libcurl seems to always replace the combination CRLF with only LF when doing the transfer. For example, the following file:

```
\CR\LF
a
```

is downloaded as:

```
\LF
a
```

My code for downloading the file is like:

```
std::string request = "RETR " + file;
FILE *newfile = fopen(newfilePath.c_str(), "wb");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, fwrite);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, newfile);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, request.c_str());
curl_easy_perform(curl);
fclose(newfile);
```

I've tried different fixes, like sending a "TYPE I" request before, setting CURLOPT_TRANSFERTEXT to 0L (binary) and setting CURLOPT_CRLF to 0L (don't convert) but it doesn't seem to work.

Any idea of what it could be?

Comment: ... and that is why we don't use FTP anymore. On a more serious note: tell your debugger to break on calls to `fwrite` and inspect the passed buffer. That will tell you if curl is doing the CRLF translation or if it happens as part of writing the file. The options you mentioned are both set to 0 by default, so I would be surprised if curl still does the translation. It might also be worth using `strace` on your process. That way you see what the server sends as well. For all you know the server is broken.

Comment: I suggest adding the option `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);`. It helps a lot when debugging `libcurl` programs

Comment: @Botje I've actually redirected the curl output to a string buffer and it's still wrong, so it's not a fwrite problem. And about the server, I've tried the ftp command on the client machine and it downloads it correctly as long as the option 'binary' is used first, which I've already done in my code with the TYPE I request

Comment: I suggest you snoop on the FTP control connection and see what Curl sends out, then. As far as I can see, it defaults to binary transfers.

Comment: @Botje I'm doing the following requests: USER (user), PASS (password), EPSV, TYPE A, TYPE I, NLST, EPSV, NLST, EPSV, RETR (file). The ftp program does the same requests, except for the EPSV (which I've already tried disabling and happens the same) and the NLST (which I use before to see what files must be downloaded)